# Java shape class: non integer coordinate polgons, especially triangles

Tags: java, polygon, shapes, mesh

never posted a question before though plenty of lurking, thanks for all the advice you've already unwittingly supplied! Couldn't seem to find any previous answers to help with this. I'm a scientist who's only picked up programming on the fly so tend to be a bodger, hopefully the question makes sense.

How do I set up an java.awt.geom.Area object for a set of triangles (for which I have the coordinates of the corners)?

The problem I’m trying to solve is that I have a mesh of triangles over which I'm drawing a mesh of rectangles and I’m trying to find for each rectangle which triangle or triangles it lies within. The java.awt.geom.Area class has an intersect method  which given sufficient looping would seem to solve it - my problem is constructing the areas.

I can create the square mesh as areas in the following (possibly inefficient) manner

```
Rectangle2D.Double[] squareMesh = new Rectangle2D.Double[totalCells];
int k = 0;
for(int i=0; i < cellsY; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < cellsX; j++) {
        squareMesh[k]= new Rectangle2D.Double(cellsXCoords[j],cellsYCoords[i],resolution,resolution);
        k++;
    }
}        

Area[] squareMeshAreas = new Area[totalCells];

for(int i=0; i < totalCells; i++) {
    squareMeshAreas[i] = new Area(squareMesh[i]);          
}
```

For the triangles I have the coordinates of the corners for each. The java.awt.Polygon looked hopeful but won't work as it only takes integer coordinates. What is the best way to set up Areas for these triangles?

If there are better ways of solving the problem without using Area class then suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: If your coordinates are `float`s, perhaps you could scale them up so you could represent them as `int`s. E.g. multiply by 1000, 10000, or whatever your level of precision is.

Comment: It looks like the [`java.awt.geom.Area`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class has a constructor `Area(Shape s)`. I also notice that there doesn't seem to already be a standard library Triangle class that implements the [Shape interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). Maybe you could create your own _custom_ Triangle, implement `Shape`, and attempt to pass objects of that type to the `Area` constructor.

Comment: Cheers.
Converting the coordinates to int by multiplying would work, I’ll probably end up passing this to one or two other people to use on their own meshes for which different precisions may be necessary though so is rather inelegant but looks like the easiest solution.
Writing a triangle class which has to mesh with existing shape interface/area class  is probably  beyond my limited java ability and time at the moment, though would be a good exercise for me to learn sometime, will have to do some more learning about interfaces...Thought I was missing something obvious but maybe not.